# What is realtime api that Facebook or Twitter use to show news feed update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, twitter

I'm wondering and don't think they use AJax such as `setInterval()` to request to the server every seconds. This isn't good way if there are million of users request in same time. What exactly is the tool they are using? It may socket.io or XMPP?

But I've seen in left slider bar listing name of online friends they might use this because when a connections was lost message show "reconnecting in 3,2,1 second(s)".

I asked this question because I don't want to use a lot of requests from clients like this.

MY JAVA SCRIPT

```
</script>

function getupdate(){
    $('#newsfeed').load('getnewsfeed.php');
    $('#notify').load('getnewnoti.php');
    $('#message').load('getnewmessage.php');
}

setInterval( "getupdate()", 5000 );
</script>
```

Some divs don't update I don't know why. Ajax load doesn't support multi-load call?

Help or suggest will be truly appropriated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that this is one "API" or one method to do the live updates, but I can tell you about a few techniques that I know of to direct you in the right direction.

Javascript `setInterval()` might work but it would not be ideal for this goal.

However there is a more complicated approach which is HTTP persistent connection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Another is the HTML5 Server-sent events, using javascript listens to page update from the server. See this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp